# Where is the clipboard feature in Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, clipboard

My question refers to the clipboard feature in word 2013. I am currently a college student and during a test, I had difficulty with my answers to the following questions. Actually, my problem lies with the answer choice that were provided.

Questions:

1. Which group on the home tab contains the cut, copy, and paste options?
2. With what task pane, can you collect up to 24 items and then paste them in various locations in the document?

Answers to choose from:

1. Office clipboard (Answer to question 2)
2. Clipboard (Answer to question 1)

   Nowhere in our textbook does it state that either of these locations are named the "Office Clipboard". #1 question defines the clipboard group, and #2 question defines the clipboard task pane.

So, not only did I have one answer wrong, I in turn had two wrong. I do not believe I was given a fair chance to answer correctly since the topic of "Office CLipboard" is not covered in our learning materials.

I actually would like to know if "Office Clipboard" is the true answer to either one of these questions, for my own piece of mind. This is driving me crazy because I feel as though I was cheated.

I do not believe that "Office Clipboard" was the answer to either of these locations.

Comment: "I feel as though I was cheated". With questions as pointless as this, yes, you should feel cheated.

Answer (score 2):

#### Which group on the home tab contains the cut, copy, and paste options?

The "home tab" on Office 2013 looks like this:

> [image]

It is very clear that the name of the group containing `cut`, `copy`, and `paste` is **Clipboard** (the name is at the bottom of the group).

So the answer to:

> 1) Which group on the home tab contains the cut, copy, and paste options?

is **Clipboard**.

---

#### With what task pane, can you collect up to 24 items and then paste them?

If you click on the little arrow at the bottom right of the **Clipboard** group it will display the **Office Clipboard**.

> [image]
>
> Each selection appears in the Clipboard, with the latest at the top. You can copy (or cut) 24 items, and they stay in the Clipboard until you close all your Office programs.
>
> [image]

So the answer to:

> 2) With what task pane, can you collect up to 24 items and then paste them in various locations in the document?

is **Office Clipboard**.

---

#### Further reading

- [The Ribbon's Tabs in Word 2007 - Word 2013/365](http://addbalance.com/word/ribbons.htm)
- [Use the Office Clipboard](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Use-the-Office-Clipboard-028903c7-66ea-4eb0-b0a1-bacdb952e3a1)